# NSIS how to sign installer

Tags: ssl, nsis

I have a NSIS script that I use to generate an installer for Microsoft Windows operating system. Installer is currently working from Windows XP and beyond.

However I would like to sign it in order to avoid the final user get the warning message before starting the installation. I know it is possible and there are several posts in stack overflow about using sign tool command.

What I have not found are:

- a step by step guide
- can I buy from any SSL provider ? how to extract from SSL certificate the required information ? (PFX)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS:

```
!finalize 'sign.bat "%1"' ; %1 inside the batch file is the .exe to sign
!uninstfinalize 'sign.bat "%1"'
```

What you put in sign.bat depends on your toolchain. If you are using the Windows SDK it would be [Signtool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool).

Before you can do any of this you have to pick a certificate authority that lets you Authenticode sign (incomplete list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995347(v=msdn.10))) with a timestamp server. Ideally you would sign with [both SHA256 and SHA1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/authenticode-signing-for-game-developers#using-a-trusted-certificate-authority).

> if you want to integrate into the Windows Error Reporting (WER) service, you should consider using VeriSign to issue the certificate, because accessing the WER database requires a WinQual account which [requires a VeriSign ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/authenticode-signing-for-game-developers#using-a-trusted-certificate-authority).